# Webservice call from VBScript

Tags: web-services, soap, vbscript

I am trying to call webservice from VBS . I am getting the error "Type mismatch in the line "objSOAP.sSOAPRequest=". I tried removing the input inside archive tag of it . Then this error is not coming. encodeBase64 and fieldvalue2(which are inside the soap xml in archive and folder tags respectively) are output of another vbs code where zip file is converted to a base64 value(its huge).fieldvalue2 is a small string.

```
Class ServiceRequest 
 Private oWinHttp,sContentType 
 Public sWebServiceURL, sSOAPRequest,sResponse,servicename,sHost 

Private Sub Class_Initialize 
 Set oWinHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1") 

'Web Service Content Type 
 sContentType ="text/xml;charset=UTF-8" 

End Sub 

Public Function SetSoapAction(servicename) 

sWebServiceURL = "http://s05ast0026-  c05.nl.eu.abnamro.com:12726/EngageOneWS/TemplateService" 
 End Function 

Public Function SendRequest 
 sHost="pb.com" 
 'Open HTTP connection  
oWinHttp.Open "POST", sWebServiceURL, False 

'Setting request headers  
oWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", sContentType 

'Send SOAP request 
 oWinHttp.Send  sSOAPRequest 

'Get XML Response 
 sResponse = oWinHttp.ResponseText 
 End Function 

Public Function Close 
 Set oWinHttp = Nothing 
 End Function 


End Class 


    Set objSOAP = New ServiceRequest
    objSOAP.SetSoapAction("Bananas") ---- > simply passing can be avoided
    objSOAP.sSOAPRequest="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:tem=""http://pb.com/EngageOne/ws/template"" xmlns:com=""http://pb.com/EngageOne/ws/common""><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><tem:ImportTemplate><com:authContext><com:UsernameToken> <com:domain><com:ident><com:name>EngageOne</com:name></com:ident></com:domain><com:userId>s03217</com:userId><com:transientSession>false</com:transientSession><com:ondemand>false</com:ondemand></com:UsernameToken></com:authContext><com:context><com:domain><com:ident><com:name>EngageOne</com:name></com:ident></com:domain><com:user><com:id>s03217</com:id></com:user></com:context><archive>"&encodeBase64&"</archive><folder><ident><com:id></com:id><com:name>"& fieldvalue2 &"</com:name></ident></folder><effectiveDate>?</effectiveDate><withdrawnDate>?</withdrawnDate></tem:ImportTemplate></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"



objSOAP.SendRequest 
 sResponse = objSOAP.sResponse
msgBox(sResponse)
```

Comment: Have the variables `encodeBase64` and `fieldvalue2` been purposely omitted from your code or are they empty variables used in your code that you have not populated yet?

Comment: Also, your `SetSoapAction()` should not be set to `Bananas`, that was just the example used in the technet article you got this class file from. This should be where your webservice name is stored.

Comment: I know. I am not using anything that is being  passed so kept as is since I was trying out options.
encodeBase64 & fieldvalue2  is already populated

Comment: I doubt a URL in `sWebServiceURL` is valid with a space in it.